# database design for sharing post from another user

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I'm developing a social network

my problem is how can i design  sharing post in the database

what i have now

```
user table
```

and

`post table` has a foreign key to `user id`

and

`like table` contain two foreign key `user id` vs `post id`

what i'm looking for is to have  any small solution for sharing  post from a user and connect this solution with like table because  if some one share a post he will get new like on it

I dont know if creating  a new `share table` is good but what about like now  ?

any idea please ?

Answer (score 6):

So, to sum up, you have:

- Users
- Posts

  - references Users
- Shares

  - references Users
  - references Posts
- Likes

  - references Users
  - references Posts or Shares

The SQL implementation of this domain model would be:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int NOT NULL autoincrement
);
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int NOT NULL autoincrement,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
CREATE TABLE shares (
    id int NOT NULL autoincrement,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    post_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id)
);
CREATE TABLE likes (
    id int NOT NULL autoincrement,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    post_id int,  /* NULLABLE */
    share_id int,  /* NULLABLE */
    CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_shares FOREIGN KEY (share_id) REFERENCES shares (id)
);
```

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but, here it goes. What if I have a `share count` feature. Normally `OP` posts something and then `User B` shares that post and then `OP`s post gets a `share count` of 1. Now, from what I understood so far in your database structure, If `User C` shared the shared post of `User B`, then the `share count` would be credited to `OP`s original post, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is no actual "shared post of User B", so everything is credited to the original post.

Comment: It would be great if the share count will be credited to `User B`. To do it, I think adding a flag column, perhaps `is_shared` would do the thing. Anyways, thanks for the clarifying.